# Override Commerce Kickstart Features ( and Features Override module error)

Tags: features, commerce

I have the Drupal Commerce Kickstart bundle in my project. This bundle contains a bunch of Features. Most of them are overridden now. It's not good to have most of setting inside the DB instead of features, so I want to save my changes inside my features.

As far as I know, it's not a good idea to modify the Kickstart Features, so I tried to use the Features Override module.

But, unfortunately, got "white screen of death" on Feautures Override Tab. Also, it broke all of my Kickstart Features.

The only "evidence" is the message:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   features_override_features_export_render_addition()

PHP: 5.4.9
Commerce Kickstart: 7.x-2.9
Features Override: 7.x-2.0-rc1

Do you have any ideas how to fix this problem with Featuers Override, or just how can I move my settings from DB to code in my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Features Override works nicely in simple scenarios, but I've been unable to get it working in more complex scenarios, such as modifying Drupal Commerce.

One alternative — instead of modifying the Features Components provided by Drupal Commerce — is to **clone them, make your changes to the cloned components, and then featurize the cloned components**.